# Why routes are loaded even the condition is not met in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

In my `App.tsx` I have set it up like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
              <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Navigation />
              </SafeAreaView>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

My Navigation component contains the logic to render authenticated or non authenticated routes based on the user and it contains this:

```
const Navigation = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Main"
              component={Auth}
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen 
              name="Users"
              component={Users}
              options={{headerShown:false}}
            />
          </Stack.Group>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="NonAuth"
            component={NonAuth}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

The `Auth` component is a `BottomTabNavigator` while the `NonAuth` is another `StackNavigator`
Inside the screens of the BottomTabNavigator I have a screen for settings and there lies the logout button, when I am clicking this button I am setting the user to null but I am getting the error  saying:
null is not an object evaluating user.role
In the BottomTabNavigator I am checking the user.role to decide what bottom tabs to show but since  the user is null why is it going inside the Auth routes, when I login it correctly goes from NonAuth to Auth automatically because on login I am setting the user to some data but on logout I set it to null and it still going inside the Auth?

These are the versions I am using:

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

Also note that the NonAuth is created using `@react-navigation/native-stack`
Navigation using `@react-navigation/stack`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition. `user` will eventually be null, but your logout screen is picking up that value first. That's normal. Program that screen to respect the possibility of a null user.

Comment: I noticed another problem because I have different colors based on user role 
in the navigationcontainer I check if there is user then get colors for the user role otherwise provide some default colors and when the app is opened it gets the user from async storage and then sets the user state but the navigation container theme is not updated to use user.role colors but is still using the default ones

Comment: for some reason react navigation is not being rerendered when the user state changes

Comment: Right, I think that's what this component is for https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#theme

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it wasn't working is because I was conditional rendering the stacks inside another stack, so I had to change it to

```
const Navigation = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return user ? (
      <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Main"
              component={Auth}
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen 
              name="Users"
              component={Users}
              options={{headerShown:false}}
            />
          </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>) : 
      <NonAuth/> }

     
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```